# clearFocus in android dialog doesn't work

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext

I have a EditText(searcField) in a android dialog, after I finished the editing, and dismiss the dialog.

then i go to other EditText, the focus is still in searchField.

Any idea?

thanks

EDIT:
there are too much to post in here, hope this can help a bit to understand my issue.

Customer dialog view

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <EditText 
                     android:id="@+id/search_field"
                     android:layout_width="0dp"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:gravity="left"
                     android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
                     android:layout_weight="0.70"
                     android:hint="type item name to search"/>


           </LinearLayout>


          <ListView    
             android:id="@+id/itemList"    
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:divider="#00000000"
             android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"    
             android:scrollbars="none"/>

      </LinearLayout>
```

Java code

```
    View searchView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search, null, false);
    EditText searchField = (EditText)productEditView.findViewById(R.id.search_field);
    searchField.addTextChangedListener(this);
    ...

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
        if (searchField.hasFocus()) {
            Log.i("MyApp", "searchField is still focused");
            return;
        }
        if (otherField.hasFocus()){
           Log.i("MyApp", "other field");
           return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you saying the focus is on a field of a dialog that is not displayed? how do you know it is focused?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the focus is still in the field of the dialog. I registered all my textFields with addTextChangedListener. Then in the afterTextChanged callback, I check if (searchField.hasFocus()), it's always true.

Comment: maybe post some code so we can better see what is going on

Comment: just added my codes, it's too much to post in here, so I just post some basic ones.

Comment: have you tried calling otherField.requestFocus() whenever you want to change focus?

Comment: Why have you deleted the question? I've spent last 10 minutes trying to help you. And now I have a solution.

Comment: sorry man, i will put it back, i thought it's not normal to ask. iw ill put it back. sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Another, albeit somewhat hacky, solution I regularly use is setting `android:focusable="true"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the parent view (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc) of a layout if I want to be able to clearFocus() of an EditText, or open the Activity/Fragment without the first EditText from being focused automatically.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it can be achieved through xml but you can do it programmatically when your dialog is dismissed by doing something like:

```
mView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mView.requestFocus();
```

To know when your dialog is dismissed simply override the onDismiss() callback method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the following code after your editing code event :

```
seachview.clearfocus();
edittext.requestfocus();
```